# How to get notified of cloud function out-of-memory errors, and why is it not the default behaviour?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

It seems that if a cloud function runs out of memory, the error does not by default end up in Stackdriver error reporting. I think it is very important to be notified of these types of errors so I am wondering why that is, and what I should do in order to be notified of all critical errors.

This is the error I see in the logs:

> Memory limit of 256 MiB exceeded with 258 MiB used. Consider increasing the memory limit, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/c

My functions are deployed using Firebase and they are generation 1. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native notification like you expected. But you can create alerts based on log:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts

Here the steps:

1. Go to Log Explorer
2. Click "Create Alert" button
3. On alert query input fill with below query (change with your app desired)

```
resource.type = "cloud_function"
resource.labels.function_name = "app"
resource.labels.region = "asia-southeast1"
 severity>=DEFAULT Consider increasing the memory limit
```

4. The view will like below:

[image]
5. Select the notification channel if you want to notify specific channel
6. Click "Save" button, and done.

Just note: You should run my given query to the log explorer first. I am not tested the query, because I don't have memory limit reach log. But I tried with similar query and it's work 100%.